# php include with condition

Tags: php, if-statement, include

Strange problem:

in the following code works both includes (both files are shown) but only one echo:

```
if (!$noParents){ 
    echo "You are parented!";
    include 'views/parentsarea.html.php'; 
} else { 
    echo "You are not parented!";
    include 'views/parentsarearegister.html.php';
}
```

Comment: Maybe browser cached the old HTML files from previous tests. Try hard-refresh - `CTRL+R` in your browser to check.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not included somewhere else ?

Comment: @Ilia Lev : Please change your validated answer. Previous was deleted and is nonsense

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Includes are adding when script is parsing.

Comment: Thank you. Is there some other way to include a file that will work with condition?

Comment: This is nonsense. Includes are done at runtime, and conditional includes work fine.

Comment: @Piotr Olaszewski: your statement is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you already have the other include done in other place of your code OR refresh your PHP server and web browser.